# I am having issues running this code, it keeps returning this error "NameError: name 'matrix' is not defined"

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14,10)) 
sns.heatmap(df.corr(method='spearman'), annot=True, mask= matrix, vmin=-1, vmax=1, center= 0, cmap= 'coolwarm',linewidths=.5)
```

Comment: Well. It isn't defined. I'm not sure why you expect it to be.

Comment: I was able to run this earlier without any errors but now i keep getting 'matrix' not defined

Comment: If you're using a notebook or an environment like Spyder, you probably defined it, then deleted something important, one line maybe, `matrix` along with it; `matrix` stayed in your variable explorer, then you deleted all your variables and now it's undefined. There is nothing to do here; you need to check what you want your code to do and what `matrix` needs to be for that.

Comment: Well again, it is *clearly not defined*. Perhaps it was before, but it isn't in the code you've shown

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind this error can be one of the below

- Either you have defined the matrix before a while ago and you are not getting this error.
- You might have imported some package that has the matrix defined.

**Solution:**
Try to find out the type of matrix and create an object of that type with matrix name